# SQL Server : convert all varchar to mm/dd/yyyy format

Tags: sql-server

I want to cast all the dates to `mm/dd/yyyy`.

My input is in `varchar`. So I want to cast it. I'm facing error when I cast

```
CAST(mmddyyy or ddmmyyy as datetime)
```

Could someone help me out?

Comment: Post your SQL code and the error you are receiving.  Also include sample input data.

Comment: Do you really have a three-digit year?

Answer (score 1):

To get the data of datetime in appropriated format you can use CONVERT function

```
DECLARE @s DATETIME

SELECT @s = CONVERT(DATETIME, '03/13/2013', 101)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sql Server? Probably requires string splitting and reassembling the date parts. Need more info from you though.

```
update data
set data = 
    dateadd(yy, cast((substring(data, 5, 3)) as int) + 1900, /* ?? */
    dateadd(dd, cast((substring(data, 3, 2)) as int) - 1,
    dateadd(mm, cast((substring(data, 1, 2)) as int) - 1, '19000101')))
```

Plenty of info out there on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Use DATEFORMAT to tell SQL how to interpret dates from text.

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
SELECT CAST('11-02-2015' as datetime)
SET DATEFORMAT mdy;
SELECT CAST('11-02-2015' as datetime)
```

[image]

More info : https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms189491.aspx